Price of power option under Black Scholes Assumptions
As in the title, is $$\pi_0(S^2_T)=S^2_0e^{rT}$$ the correct way to price power option with terminal payoff
$$X=S^2_T$$
under Black Scholes assumptions of $S_T=S_0\exp((r-\sigma^2/2)T+\sigma W_T$? Here I'm using the risk neutral pricing formula of $\pi_0(X)=e^{-rT}E_Q(X_T)$ Many thanks

No it's not. First of all, your expression for $\pi_0(S_T^2)$ is incorrect - maybe you should show the steps of your calculation - and also $S_T^2$ is not really a power option.

I suppose it is a "contract for the square of S" but not an option, it has no conditionality.

It is definitely not correct, you have forgotten the whole role of convexity (aka Jensen inequality) (set $n\ge1$)
$E(X^n) \ge (E(X))^n$
For a BS process, you have
$S_T = S_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 T + \sigma W_T}$, and
$S_T^n = S_0^n e^{n \left (-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 T + \sigma W_T \right )}$
$E(S_T^n) = S_0^n e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 T (n^2 - n)}$
which is equal to $S_0^n$ only for $n=1$ or $\sigma=0$.
